# Как избежать повторения слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

*Заморозок обещают за два **дня** до тёплого **дня**.*

(Посмотрел на Гисметео прогноз погоды в Москве на две недели, увидел -1° 24 сентября и до 21° 26-го числа, вот и произнёс про себя эту фразу.)

Как можно перефразировать, чтобы не повторялся *"день"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За два дня до резкого потепления прогнозируются заморозки.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Неплохо, только не понятно, что день этот самый тёплый ожидается. Действительно, я не написал, что он ***самый*** тёплый, но теперь говорю, что имелось в виду это.

Comment: Тогда можно "до (необычного) температурного максимума".

Comment: Спасибо! Да, мне нравится: *до температурного максимума в 21°.* :)

Answer (score 0):

Заморозок обещают за двое суток до тёплого дня.

За два дня до потепления будет заморозок.

Comment: Спасибо! Вторая фраза не совсем годится, потому что минусовую температуру обещали только в один из дней, первый из двух предшествующих. "За двое суток" тоже не совсем нравится, кажется, что звучит более официально, но тем не менее на худой конец можно и так выкрутиться.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я изначално неправильно понял содержание фразы из вопроса. Отредактировал ответ.